# No devices Android studio and flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Hi I am trying to run my Flutter project in Android studio. The device list lists "no devices" but when I run "flutter doctor" in the terminal it says 1 device connected.

I think the issue has to do with that the Android sdk is not being found by flutter, and I have to run "set ANDROID_HOME="Android path"" on each startup of the software.

Comment: You need to set that variable permanently, which is your os?

Comment: Windows 10, I added it to my PATH variable but I still need to set ANDROID_HOME on each shut down and startup.

Comment: You don't need to add it to your path, must must add it as a new environment variable

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I get you. So do I add a new user variable called ANDROID__HOME with the value of the path of the Android sdk?

Comment: Exactly, that should work

Comment: Thanks that solved it! 